# Adding Image over a Transparent JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, frame, transparent

I want to display an image over a transparent JFrame.
The image is not shown clearly.
If I add any component like JButton or anything else it is displayed well except
any component which has image inside it.

Here is a code example.

```
import java.awt.Color;
public class PunchFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public PunchFrame2() {
        initComponents();
        setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(java.awt.Color.black);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setForeground(java.awt.Color.white);
        jLabel2.setText("Steve Jobs");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,             jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(234, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(23, 23, 23))
    );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,      jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1))
    );

    jLabel3.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("/home/username/Desktop/stevejobs.png")); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(200, 200, 200)
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel3)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    setBounds((screenSize.width-545)/2, (screenSize.height-290)/2, 545, 290);
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new PunchFrame2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
// End of variables declaration    }
```

I tried many things like 
`jLabel1.setOpaque(false);`
but in vain.

How to solve this problem?

Image used:

[image: Image used]

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you link to the image used, as well as a screen-shot of the result?

Comment: After adding `pack()`, it worked for me but Windows 7, Java 7.

Comment: I tried my program today at home on windowsXP and it works very fine without any problem.But as we use Ubuntu at work,the images are not clearly shown.So it seems to me the problem with the Ubuntu not the program itself. I will link you the image used and the screen-shot of the result on Saturday because we are on weekend.Thanks

Comment: This is the image used <a href='http://postimage.org/' target='_blank'><img src='http://s12.postimage.org/m1i5q0ep5/stevejobs.png' border='0' alt="stevejobs" /></a>

Comment: This is the result: http://s10.postimage.org/bhuoxgzqx/myprogram.png @Andrew Thompson

Comment: *"Here is a code example."*  Hmmm.. given that code example does not compile, and never packs the frame (to give it a non-zero size) I find it hard to believe that is the code being used.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Here I edit my question and posted the full code using Netbeans 7.2.1 and JDK 7 on Ubuntu 12 @AndrewThompson

Comment: *"setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));"*  Is this some 1.7 thing for transparency?  It produces a solid frame using a 1.6 JRE.

Answer (score 3):

You just call `setVisible(true)`. But the default `JFrame` width and height is zero.  It will not expand the `JFrame`.

Try to set the size of `JFrame`.
there are two ways:

```
PunchFrame2 frame = new PunchFrame2();
```

1. `frame.pack(); // or`
2. `frame.setSize(300,300);`

   ```
   frame.setVisible(true);
   ```